# Query Show Same Value in Table

Tags: sql, oracle

How do you create a query will show all data that contains the same value in name. Is this possible. This was similar to my first question yesterday. Using only the name in the query

For example - table 1:

| ID | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2 |
| 2 | Mark | 10 |
| 3 | Ken | 20 |
| 4 | john | 2 |
| 5 | Nick | 12 |
| 6 | nick | 23 |
| 7 | nick jones | 32 |
| 8 | Hamil | 42 |
| 9 | John | 2 |

Desired output:

| ID | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2 |
| 4 | john | 2 |
| 5 | Nick | 12 |
| 6 | nick | 23 |
| 7 | nick jones | 32 |
| 9 | John | 2 |

Comment: Done @BarbarosÖzhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNT()` Analytic function such as

```sql
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT t.*, 
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(LOWER(t.name),'[^ ]+')) AS cnt
   FROM table1 t
)
SELECT ID, Name, Age
  FROM t
 WHERE cnt > 1  
 ORDER BY ID
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e83dcf26e914f02041463626a5903771)</kbd>

where need to think case insensitively, and extract the first portion of `name` in order to seperate name and surname provided only the first name is matter of interest even if there are name-surname combinations of more than two words.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that.

```
select * from #temp where Names in (
    select Names from #temp
    group by Names having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: It only show the the same value like if there is two John and one john it will only show the two John but not with small letter j

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
  WHERE Name IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Name
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY Name
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 )
 ORDER BY Name
```

with case sensitive db

```
 SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE LOWER(Name) IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(Name)
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY LOWER(Name)
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
 )
 ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: It only show the the same value like if there is two John and one john it will only show the two John but not with small letter j

Comment: This means your db is setup as case sensitive

Comment: I see. but this code will show all that has the same name right?

Comment: it will convert all names to lower case when searching so "John" will be the same as "john"

Answer (score 0):

You can also use EXISTS. Convert both names to upper case to get both 'john' and 'John' rows.

```
select a.* 
from table_1 a
where exists(select 1
             from table_1 b
             where a.id <> b.id and UPPER(a.name) = UPPER(b.name))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Persenel
  WHERE LOWER(Name) IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(Name)
      FROM Persenel
      GROUP BY LOWER(Name)
      HAVING COUNT(LOWER(PName)) > 1
 )
ORDER BY Name
```